# How to check whether a certain window is open swift

Tags: swift, nswindow

I want to present a window programmatically when a button is pressed. But currently the issue is that after the window is open, if I press the button for a second time a second window opens. I want to change this behaviour to bring the window to focus on the second press.

Here is my current code.

```
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"),bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("windowController")) as? NSWindowController
        controller?.showWindow(self)
```

Comment: Create an optional value of a window controller in AppDelegate.  And use it every time you open its window.